# Bind event on LI not on Anchor tag inside that LI - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this kind of HTML

```
<li class="one-reference per-reference ui-draggable" item-id="8" style="position: relative;">
     <a class="moduleItemTitle" href="http://localhost/derrickpang/index.php?option=com_k2&amp;view=item&amp;id=8">Knee pains</a>
     <span class="moduleItemDateCreated">Written on Wednesday, 19 October 2016 05:58</span>
     <span class="moduleItemHits">Read 393 times</span>
     <div class="clr"></div>
 </li>
```

I have bind event on all LIs with class `per-reference`

I do not want to call function `openRefModal` when clicked on `a` tag with class `.moduleItemTitle` I just want to open that link in `href` as normal behaviour of anchor tag.

Here is what I have tried

`jQuery(".per-reference").bind("click", openRefModal);
    jQuery(".per-reference .moduleItemTitle").unbind("click", openRefModal);`

Comment: Is my answer working for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just add below code for `a` tag `moduleItemTitle` class**

```
jQuery(".per-reference").bind("click", openRefModal);
jQuery(".per-reference .moduleItemTitle" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

> Now `a` tag is released from click event.

Here is the details about [jQuery stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
$('.per-reference').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (event.target.className !== 'moduleItemTitle') {
    // do what you want here   
  }
});

$('.per-reference > .moduleItemTitle').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.location = event.target.href;
});
```